# Can we access camera in docker using Open CV

Tags: python-3.x, docker, opencv, ubuntu

I have been assigned a project to use docker and run an opencv script in which i have to use camera for real time object detection. I have seen multiple methods of working on docker. But i am unable to use camera inside a docker container. Can anyone suggest a proper method to use camera inside a docker container.

I am using this function to access camera `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and `cv2.imshow("frame",frame)` method for display.
i haven't created a docker file and i have only run the instance of ubuntu using `docker run -it ubuntu.`
Please suggest me a method to use camera inside docker container.

Comment: A design goal of Docker is that container processes can't generally access host devices.  Can you run this process directly on the host instead?  (This is probably possible, but extremely inconvenient.)

Comment: For testing the application we need to transfer the application to testing team and the problem begins from there. so we are thinking of using docker as a solution. @DavidMaze